# How to set test status as success in test unit

Tags: ruby, reporting, testunit

I am running a test using

```
gem 'test-unit'
```

Github Link: https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit

and generating report using

```
gem 'ci_reporter'
```

Github Link: https://github.com/ci-reporter/ci_reporter

```
Class Sample

  def test_sample
    # code
    notify "Notification message"
  end
end
```

Test-unit gem has following status:

```
pending
omission
notification
pass
error
failure
```

Ci-reporter gem has following status:

```
Success
Failure
```

I am running a sample test using test-unit with notification status.

When generating a report using ci-reporter gem, it shows the notification message with failure status.

Attached a report for reference [image: Notification]

I need to show the success status with notification message. How to do it?

Comment: Have you tried returning `0` or `1` after notify?

Comment: @Bala Yes tried. But did't work.

Answer (score 0):

@karan to be clear it's the CI-reporter xml report's output you want to effect, not the test's failure/passing status?  If you call `Kernel.exit 1` for a failure and do nothing (or `Kernel.exit 0`) on success, that should handle the pass/fail status, but if that's not working for CI-reporter to capture your state best to check their docs or open an issue there.  But if you just had a method return 0 or 1, they calling Kernel.exit as above, I do that in my `debt_ceiling` gem for ci integration and it works fine there.